# Unable to cast System.DBNull to System.Byte[]

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, file-upload

VB.NET and SQL Server. I'm trying to upload image on my system but it has error stating

> System.DBNull unable to cast to System.Byte[].

Here is my code

```vb
    If id <> "" Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData((Convert.ToString("SELECT ImagePic FROM masterlist WHERE id ='") & Request.QueryString("id")) + "'") 'image data will be select depend on what user search in the serch textbox
        If dt.Rows.IsNull.Count > 0 Then
            Dim bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0).IsNull(0)("ImagePic"), Byte())
            Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            Image1.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:images/png;base64,") & base64String
        Else
            Image1.ImageUrl = ""
            Image1.AlternateText = "No image present in database with the name" 'if there is no image  in db the messege will display
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I get error at this line

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0).IsNull(0)("ImagePic"), Byte())
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Use `dt.Rows(0).IsNull(0)` to test whether you have a value before attempting to convert.

Comment: You need to check if you have a dbnull prior to casting. If it is dbnull, do not cast.

Comment: @DaleK i use that code but it state "Expreesion is not an array or a method and cannot have an argument list".

Comment: Use the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=netcore-3.1) - they will solve 99% of any issues you have.

Comment: If you tried to do as suggested and it didn't work then you did it wrong because `IsNull` is a method, so you would not get a message telling you that it's not. Show us what you did so we can see what you did wrong. Update the question with the new code.

Comment: This is silly: `GetData((Convert.ToString("SELECT ImagePic FROM masterlist WHERE id ='") & Request.QueryString("id")) + "'")`. Why would you need to convert a `String` to a `String`? Why would you use `&` and `+` to do the same job in the same line? Why would you put parentheses around one of the concatenations? Instead, use this: `GetData("SELECT ImagePic FROM masterlist WHERE id ='" & Request.QueryString("id") & "'")` or, even better, this: `GetData($"SELECT ImagePic FROM masterlist WHERE id ='{Request.QueryString("id")}'")`.

Comment: Again with this:`Convert.ToString("data:images/png;base64,") & base64String`. Why do you think that you need to call `Convert.ToString` and pass a `String` as an argument? What do you think that is accomplishing?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i didnt do this system thats why i need you guys opinion because i stuck to fix this problem i try to save and retrieve image but always failed with this code

Answer (score 0):

This:

```vb
Dim bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0).IsNull(0)("ImagePic"), Byte())
```

is not what you were told to do. The point of `IsNull` is to tell you whether the field is NULL and, therefore, whether there is any data to read. You check whether it is NULL first and then only read data if there is data to read. Given the code you already have, the sensible change would be from this:

```vb
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
```

to this:

```vb
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso Not dt.Rows(0).IsNull(0) Then
```

That checks whether there is a row and that the row contains data.